# error, == won't work, input == letter don't work

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-------------------------------------- Hot HTML Head ------------------------------------------->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Table hiragana</title>
    <!------------------------------------- CSS sheesh ----------------------------------------->
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0; color: rgb(40,40,40); text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px;
                font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
            }
                .menu {
                    display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; margin-top: 1%;
                }
                .menu , a {
                    font-size: 12px; margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%;
                }
            #container {
                margin-top: 10%;
            }

        </style>
</head>

<!-------------------------------------- Hot HTML Bod ------------------------------------------->
<body>
    <center>
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
            <a href="table.html">TABLE</a>
            <a href="random.html">RANDOM</a>
        </div>

        <div id="container">
            <p id="japanletter">letter</p>
            <input id="input"></input>
            <p onclick='run()' style="cursor:pointer;padding:10px;background-color:#eee;width:50px;margin:1%;font-size:12px;">check</p>
            <p id="status">status</p>
        </div>
    </center>

    <script>
        // randomize the letter
        function randomize() {
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1 , letter = "" , input = "";  // output will 1-46 because hiragana table has 46 chars

            // process randomizer for letter
            if (random == 1) {
                letter = "あ";
            }
            else {
                letter = "い";
            }

        // output random letters
        document.getElementById('japanletter').innerHTML = letter;

        }

        // onblur get value from input
        function run() {
            // get value in input
            var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
            compare();
        }

        // function compare letter and input
        function compare() {
                // if input equivalent letter
                if (input == letter) {
                    // output them and direct to return randomize
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "correct";
                    randomize();
                }
            }

        // call out function
        randomize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please learn about variable scope. `input` is not in scope inside your compare() function. It only exists inside your run() function, nowhere else. Similarly `letter` does not appear to be defined either. Do you have any errors in your browser's Console?

Comment: thank you, now I know what the problem is even called... I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just move out the two variables `input` and `letter` out of the method `randomize()`, so that it can be accessed in the other methods `run()` (to fetch value for `input`) and `compare()` (to compare the two values `input` and `letter`).

Please try the following codes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-------------------------------------- Hot HTML Head ------------------------------------------->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Table hiragana</title>
    <!------------------------------------- CSS sheesh ----------------------------------------->
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0; color: rgb(40,40,40); text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px;
                font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
            }
                .menu {
                    display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; margin-top: 1%;
                }
                .menu , a {
                    font-size: 12px; margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%;
                }
            #container {
                margin-top: 10%;
            }

        </style>
</head>

<!-------------------------------------- Hot HTML Bod ------------------------------------------->
<body>
    <center>
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
            <a href="table.html">TABLE</a>
            <a href="random.html">RANDOM</a>
        </div>

        <div id="container">
            <p id="japanletter">letter</p>
            <input id="input"></input>
            <p onclick='run()' style="cursor:pointer;padding:10px;background-color:#eee;width:50px;margin:1%;font-size:12px;">check</p>
            <p id="status">status</p>
        </div>
    </center>

    <script>
    // randomize the letter 1-46 because hiragana table has 46 chars
        var letter = "" , input = "";  // output will
        function randomize() {
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;

            // process randomizer for letter
            if (random == 1) {
                letter = "あ";
            }
            else {
                letter = "い";
            }

        // output random letters
        document.getElementById('japanletter').innerHTML = letter;

        }

        // onblur get value from input
        function run() {
            // get value in input
            input = document.getElementById('input').value;
            compare();
        }

        // function compare letter and input
        function compare() {
                // if input equivalent letter
                if (input == letter) {
                    // output them and direct to return randomize
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "correct";
                    randomize();
                }
            }

        // call out function
        randomize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll avoid downvotes if you take the time to explain your answer.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your reminder, I have edited the answer to describe the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare `letter` & `input` variables to global scope so that it would be available into another functions also. Using `var letter = ""` will limit `letter` to be scope for current `function` only.

[Click here to learn more about scope](https://javascript.info/closure)

Below is updated code and you can test with run code snippet.

```js
var letter = "",
    input = ""; // output will 1-46 because hiragana table has 46 chars

// randomize the letter
function randomize() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;    

  // process randomizer for letter
  if (random == 1) {
    letter = "あ";
  } else {
    letter = "い";
  }

  // output random letters
  document.getElementById('japanletter').innerHTML = letter;

}

// onblur get value from input
function run() {
  // get value in input
  input = document.getElementById('input').value;
  compare();
}

// function compare letter and input
function compare() {

  // if input equivalent letter
  if (input == letter) {
    // output them and direct to return randomize
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "correct";
    randomize();
  } else {  
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "incorrect";
  }
}

// call out function
randomize();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 1%;
}

.menu,
a {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

#container {
  margin-top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<title>Table hiragana</title>


<center>
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
    <a href="table.html">TABLE</a>
    <a href="random.html">RANDOM</a>
  </div>

  <div id="container">
    <p id="japanletter">letter</p>
    <input id="input" />
    <p onclick='run()' style="cursor:pointer;padding:10px;background-color:#eee;width:50px;margin:1%;font-size:12px;">check</p>
    <p id="status">status</p>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: thank you for showing explaining me my own error, I at first want to search for it but I don't know what's problem is categorized and called. :D